# Prevent the content to scroll down with the mouse scroll unless by using the scroll bar

Tags: css, web, scroll, non-scrolling

How can I make the content none scrollable by the mouse wheel, but instead, can only be scrolled down using the scroll bar.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youcan bind `touchstart` event, but there is no scrollbar on mobile, so how would user scroll?

```
$("body").bind("mousewheel, touchstart", function() {
     return false;
});
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pdhLwhv/2/)

Comment: Thanks! But, is there a way that the user cannot scroll the content itself, but there is still a scrollbar in the right part that they will use to scroll (something like mouse ticking the scroll bar and drags it down in our desktop.) Thanks so much..

Comment: You can make fake scrollbar, for example [like in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pdhLwhv/3/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery. something like this

```
$("body").bind("mousewheel", function() {
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! that works perfectly, but how about if I try to access my page in android or ios device, Because I thought, the mouse-wheel represents the scrolling using our finger in our phone, the content still scrolls in phone devices. Sorry for bad english. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Well I find this solution

touch-action: pan-x;

it will allow you to click the content but will unable to scroll it down